# this.props function not triggering when called with callback function - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a bit of trouble having two of my components communicating with one another. In my parent component, I pass props to a Modal (the child component) like this:

```
<ReopenRequestModal
    {...this.state.ReopenModalData}
    show={this.state.isReopenModalShown}
    onHide={this.closeReopenModal}
    onReopenRequestSubmitClick={this.changeSignOffStatus}
    userInfo={this.props.userInfo}
/>
```

and then in my child component, I am trying to validate if a text area has < 20 characters before the user submits it by clicking on a button:

```
<ActionButton
        className="default"
        buttonText="SUBMIT"
        onClick={ () =>
          (this.state.value < 20 ?
            this.props.dispatch(notificationActions.addInfoNotification({
              title: 'Warning',
              message: 'Justification text should be at least 20 characters long',
            })) : this.props.onReopenRequestSubmitClick)}
 />
```

I'm using a callback function so it will only be triggered when the actual button is clicked on. The `this.props.dispatch` function works as intended, however the `this.props.onReopenRequestSubmitClick` (which lives in the parent component) does not. I can get both actions to work on their own, but when I try to incorporate the two using a ternary operator, etc. it is not working. Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: you need to add  `()` to run `this.props.onReopenRequestSubmitClick()`

Answer (score 4):

You aren't calling the function. Add `()` at the end of `this.props.onReopenRequestSubmitClick`:

```
<ActionButton
        className="default"
        buttonText="SUBMIT"
        onClick={ () =>
          (this.state.value < 20 ?
            this.props.dispatch(notificationActions.addInfoNotification({
              title: 'Warning',
              message: 'Justification text should be at least 20 characters long',
            })) : this.props.onReopenRequestSubmitClick() )}
 />
```